# Is there a way to capture multiple checkboxs and select box items?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, loops

a I have a very large form with a lot of ckeckbox and a select multiple list.

All this options are like something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" />chk1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" />chk2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3" />chk3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk4" id="chk4" />chk4<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1_group2" id="chk1_group2" />A<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2_group2" id="chk2_group2" />B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3_group2" id="chk3_group2" />C<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk4_group2" id="chk4_group2" />D<br />
```

My idea is to take al the values and save them in one sigle value like this:

```
String chk = "chk1, chk2, chk3";
String chk_group2 = "A,B,D";
```

I'm looking for a loop that can take all the vaules from the request and put the values in a sigle string. I'm tried whith List but it's not working.
I'm using JSP and a Oracle 10g DB

THK

Comment: Is this client-side that you want to build your lists? Or after the post back to server?

Comment: after post back to server.

but if is client side, i will do something to sending to the server. So anyway will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first give every checkbox a "group" attribute (or something equally distinguishing), to specify what group it should represent, like so :

```
...
<input type="checkbox" group="group1" name="chk4" id="chk4" />chk4<br />
<input type="checkbox" group="group2" name="chk1_group2" id="chk1_group2" />A<br />
...
```

then parse them with something like this:

```
var group1 = [];
var group2 = [];

function parseSelected(){
    // maybe a more specific query for this 
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var checkbox=checkboxes[i];
            // if its not checked, continue... 
        if(!checkbox.checked) continue;
        if(checkbox.getAttribute("group")=="group1"){
            group1.push(checkbox.getAttribute("name"));
        } else if(checkbox.getAttribute("group")=="group2"){
            group2.push(checkbox.getAttribute("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

and on some event somewhere (form submit possibly?)

```
parseSelected();
var strGroup1 = group1.join(', ');
var strGroup2 = group2.join(', ');
```

Comment: My answer assumed you were looking for javascript, I thought I saw a javascript tag up there.  OOPS!

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled upon this question.. even though it's been posted a long time, others may find it helpful as well.

You can access the checkboxes easily using jquery.each; e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('th input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
            $('td input:checkbox', table).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
});
```